# How to persist firebase-auth over refresh with Nuxt?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to set up Firebase authentication and currently, a user can sign up and I store their information within Vuex store.

If I refresh I lose everything and I do not know how to have it persist over the refresh. Could I use local storage, cookies, plugins? what would be the best way I have looked at a lot of answers and am still unclear.

I have tried using middleware but with no luck. I have also dabbled with using `authStateChanged()` but don't know where to implement it.

```
signup() {
  // checking if username exists within our database
  // creates a user through email and password
  if(this.username && this.email && this.password) {
      this.slug = slugify(this.username, {
          replacement:'-',
          remove: /[$*_+~.()'"\-:@]/g,
          lower: true
      })
      // is creating a variable that stores slug then checks whether it exists, if it does we send feedback
      let ref = db.collection('users').doc(this.slug)
      ref.get().then( (doc) => {
          if(doc.exists) {
              this.feedback ="This Username already exists"
          } else {
             firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.email, this.password)
              .then((cred) => {
                  console.log("below is CREDANTIALS")
                  console.log(cred.user)
                  ref.set({
                      username: this.username,
                      user_id: cred.user.uid
                  })
                  this.$store.commit('setUser', cred.user.uid)
                  this.$store.commit('setUsername', this.username)
                  // localStorage.setItem('user_id', cred.user.uid)
              })
              .then(() => {
                  this.$router.push({name: 'explore'})
              })
              .catch(err => {
                  console.log(err)
                  // err is caught by catch and has a property called message
                  this.feedback = err.message
              })
              }

          })
      }
  }
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

@TheWarderCoder Hey this is the snippet for saving to localstorage.

Just make a function inside methods.

```
   saveUserData(id) {
    localStorage.setItem('user-id', id)
   }
```

and call it like this inside your signup methods.

```
   this.saveUserData(id)
```

Good lucks !

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this plugin. https://github.com/robinvdvleuten/vuex-persistedstate

Nuxt.js integration is used like:

```
    // nuxt.config.js

    plugins: [{ src: '~/plugins/localStorage.js', ssr: false }]
```

```
    // ~/plugins/localStorage.js

    import createPersistedState from 'vuex-persistedstate'

    export default ({store}) => {
      window.onNuxtReady(() => {
        createPersistedState({
            key: 'yourkey',
            paths: [...]
            ...
        })(store)
      })
    }
```